# Start pulseaudio as daemon in Linux Mint 18.1

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, daemon

Linux Mint 18.1 ships with *pulseaudio* version 8.0 as sound system. 
On linuxmint 17.3 I have version 4.0 and `/etc/init/pulseaudio.conf` file where pulseadio is configure to get started with line

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

Copying file to `/etc/init` did not work.
I need this because of multiseat configuration.

Comment: Controll with `ps ps -ef | grep pulse` if it is realy not running.

Comment: nope, it is not running.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep pulse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in system.pa. I found in manual that in system wide daemon configuration should not use automatic detection.

from pulseaudio manual pages:

```
   --disallow-module-loading[=BOOL]
          Disallow module loading after startup. This is a security feature since it disallows additional module loading during runtime and on user request. It is highly recommended when --system is used (see above). Note however, that this breaks certain fea‐
          tures like automatic module loading on hot plug.
```

So I disabled (commented) lines from system.pa

```
    ### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
    #.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
    #load-module module-udev-detect
    #.else
    #### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev/hal support)
    #load-module module-detect
    #.endif
```

and now works.